# php equivalent of js search

Tags: javascript, php, search

I need to convert this JS code to PHP but I don't know what is the equivalent in PHP for string.search(pattern)

JS

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$/;
if (CodiceFiscale.search(pattern) == -1) { }
```

PHP

```
$pattern = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]\$", "");
if ($CodiceFiscale.search($pattern) == -1) { }
```

Also I'm not sure if PHP RegExp is correctly converted.

Comment: Here are the RegExp funtions in php: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeff for the hint.
I solved with preg_match().

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]\$/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $text) == false) {}
```